# Debugging possible memory corruption

Tags: c++, debugging

I have what seems to be a memory corruption in my application but it seems I cannot find the source of it with any of the following tools: **gdb, valgrind, address sanitizer, rr** (seems like my processor is too old for this).

I found out about the problem because our signal handler reports a signal when accessing that specific memory.

Valgrind was slightly helpful in saying that I have an invalid read of size 8 (because that memory is accessed through the pointer) and **asan** reported that the pointer, which in code is of type A*, is actually an unrelated type B.

Sadly I cannot give a ***sscce*** so I'd like to know how would one continue debugging in this situation ? are there any other tools I could try ?

- Platform is RHEL linux kernel version 3.10
- Compiler GCC 6.3.1

Comment: Have you considered logging some progress to reduce the area where the bug happens? Also, why can't you run the code in a debugger?

Comment: The application in question is HUGE and I've already reduced as much as I could. I did not say I cannot run the code in a debugger, I already tried gdb but it simply catches the signal caused by accessing the memory and this does not help in finding why that memory is corrupted.

Comment: Posting *full* Valgrind error could help to answer your question.

Comment: @ks1322 the only output of valgrind is, as I said, an invalid read of size 8 in the same function reported by asan

Comment: Valgrind often gives line numbers and other useful information. Make sure you have debugging information turned on.

Comment: @user4581301 I have everything built in debug mode and valgrind does give line information correctly indicating the troublesome pointer but that is not the source of the corruption ! I need to find out from where/how that memory was corrupted, information which valgrind does not give (at least in my case)

Comment: you can use valgrind in gdb which results in a break everytime valgrind find a potentially problem

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a suggestion how to proceed. First some assumptions:

- You know how to reproduce the bug.
- It's not a random corruption but in one place or at least a restricted area.

The basic idea is that you regularly trigger the access to the corrupted area that causes the signal. This increases the likelihood that the corruption is detected close to the point that caused it. For that, I'd suggest using a simple object that takes the data structure in construction and validates it:

```
struct validator
{
    validator(data_structure const& data):
        m_data(data)
    {
        validate();
    }
    ~validator()
    {
        validate();
    }
    void validate()
    {
        // Code that walks over the data structure
        // and possibly trips over corruptions.
    }
    data_structure const& m_data;
};
```

Just sprinkle instances of this throughout your code. When going through the generated crashes, you will find that some happen in areas that don't usually have anything to do with that data structure while others happen in code that really uses the data structure. This distinction is completely meaningless, because the fact that it detects the corruption doesn't mean it caused the corruption! However, if you collect more and more of these crashes, you will find that some code is more likely to be involved, and exactly that code should be surveyed more closely.

The larger the effort is to reproduce the bug, the more difficult it becomes to collect meaningful amounts of data. Therefore, it becomes important to be able to reproduce what you did and what results you received. I would therefore move the bug hunt to a separate branch in version control and include a file with a protocol in version control, too. Of course, that branch isn't intended to be merged back, but it provides relevant context information.